# Docker COPY only copies one sub-directory, not whole build context

Tags: maven, docker, build, copy, quarkus

I have create a dummy project with [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io/)' Maven archetype in Java. I want to copy the whole build context into my Docker container.

When I perform `ls -al` in the current directory I get this result:

```
drwxr-xr-x  12 my.user  staff    384 19 Aug 15:57 .
drwxr-xr-x  12 my.user  staff    384 19 Aug 15:39 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 my.user  staff     53 19 Aug 15:39 .dockerignore
-rw-r--r--   1 my.user  staff    295 19 Aug 15:39 .gitignore
drwxr-xr-x   7 my.user  staff    224 19 Aug 15:45 .idea
drwxr-xr-x   3 my.user  staff     96 19 Aug 15:39 .mvn
-rw-r--r--   1 my.user  staff     78 19 Aug 15:57 Dockerfile
-rwxrwxr-x   1 my.user  staff  10078 19 Aug 15:39 mvnw
-rw-rw-r--   1 my.user  staff   6609 19 Aug 15:39 mvnw.cmd
-rw-r--r--   1 my.user  staff   3691 19 Aug 15:39 pom.xml
drwxr-xr-x   4 my.user  staff    128 19 Aug 15:39 src
drwxr-xr-x  15 my.user  staff    480 19 Aug 15:40 target
```

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3-jdk-11-slim
WORKDIR /home/mvn
COPY ./ .
RUN ls -al
RUN mvn verify
```

Unfortunately only the target folder gets copied. This is the resulting output from `docker build .`:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  8.425MB
Step 1/5 : FROM maven:3-jdk-11-slim
 ---> b67032e30f89
Step 2/5 : WORKDIR /home/mvn
 ---> Running in 90dc6171c4be
Removing intermediate container 90dc6171c4be
 ---> 3cf149c09c43
Step 3/5 : COPY ./ .
 ---> bf0869cf8577
Step 4/5 : RUN ls -al
 ---> Running in 733891348a3c
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:00 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:00 ..
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 19 14:00 target
Removing intermediate container 733891348a3c
 ---> f425feab5580
Step 5/5 : RUN mvn verify
 ---> Running in 29e2dae052f6
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.078 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-19T14:00:51Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/home/mvn). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
The command '/bin/sh -c mvn verify' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

What could be the error here?

Comment: Something was added to your `.dockerignore` I guess.

Comment: @atline thank you, that's the solution!

Comment: Would you like to post your solution @HaroldL.Brown for future users to have an idea of what is needed to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Quarkus Maven archetype added a `.dockerignore` file. In it only the `target` folder was not excluded from Docker. Hence only the `target` folder has been copied.